# How to playback QTP scripts in Windows server 2008 R2

Tags: qtp

My application uses Syncfusion controls and when i test it with QTP i am able to record the actions. But while playback i get the 'Object doesn't support this method or property error' exception.

This exception occurs only in Windows 2008 server (64 bit machine). Is there any patch from HP to resolve this issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Kalai

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of QTP, according to [QTP 11's PAM](http://support.openview.hp.com/selfsolve/document/KM1210389/binary/QTP11.00_ProductAvailableMatrix.pdf?searchIdentifier=2d441914%3a135a389fa9c%3a-3db1&resultType=document) (Product Availability Matrix) Windows 2008 Server 64 bit SP2 is supported with out of the box with no extra patches.

Comment: Thanks Motti, but the reported issue occurs only in 64 bit machine. I was able to run the scripts without any errors in a 32 bit machine. Does Syncfusion's controls need something to work it with the server machine?

Comment: @Kalai I'm not familiar with Syncfusion, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs due the CustomBridge.dll is loaded in the .Net 2 CLR. When this assembly tries to load your .Net 4 assemblies it fails since it is trying to load a .Net 4 assembly in the .Net 2 CLR.

To resolve this issue you need to handle some changes in registry. Try the options suggested [here](http://www.syncfusion.com/support/forums/teststudio-windows/107764)